# Setting image source for ToggleButton

Tags: android

I have a 30px x 30px png file that i would like to use as an android:src rather than an android:background. By using it as the background, and mentioning "wrap_content" for both the height and the width, the final result looks more like a 45px x 45 px.

Ideally, what i need is a mix of ImageButton and ToggleButton. I would like to have the feature of setting an android:src of ImageButton and the feature of toggling where states are saved automatically for me.

Any solution or workaround?

TIA.

Hi, It does not seem to help creating another style. The src still appears much bigger that it's original 30px x 30px.

In main.xml:

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/blah"
    style="@style/myToggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ToggleButton>
```

In Styles.xml

```
<style name="myToggle">
    <item name="android:textOn">""</item>
    <item name="android:textOff">""</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_btn_toggle_bg</item>
</style>
```

In my_btn_toggle_bg.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/myBackground" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default_small" />
    <item android:id="@+id/myToggle" android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_toggle" />
</layer-list>
```

In my_btn_toggle.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/pausebutton" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/playbutton" />
</selector>
```

playbutton.png and pausebutton.png are 30px x 30px each. But they appear much bigger when i see it laid out on the device

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make the toggle button look like whatever you want.  You just need to create a style.  Have a look in the /platforms//data/res/values/styles.xml  and search for Widget.Button.ToggleButton  It looks like this:

```
<style name="Widget.Button.Toggle">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_toggle_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textOn">@android:string/capital_on</item>
    <item name="android:textOff">@android:string/capital_off</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
</style>
```

So if you go find the btn_toggle_bg drawable you find this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default_small" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_toggle" />
</layer-list>
```

Which shows you that it uses the standard `Button` background and a drawable called btn_toggle for the src.  btn_src.xml looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_on" />
</selector>
```

Which are the two drawables that are used to show the state of the button.  They are actually called btn_toggle_{on/off}.9.png since they are 9 Patch images so they stretch to match the button size.

Comment: @CaseyB @Driod.net I tried what you said - created a new style for ToggleButton but the image src still appears large. I will edit my question and list the code i tried there. Thanks

Comment: Which Device are you using it on?

Comment: @CaseyB Xoom running on 3.1 HoneyComb. ImageButtons' are looking as expected. I am having issues only with ToggleButtons.

Comment: Then there is a chance that it is bigger than 30x30px depending on how the view is scaled to fit the larger screen.  When you look at it in the LayoutEditor how does it look?  Have you tried explicitly setting the padding and margins to 0?

Comment: Yep. I have set the padding and margins explicitly to 0dip.   android:layout_margin="0dip"
  android:padding="0dip" It looks big on the LayoutEditor as well. I note that the ImageButton's android:src looks fine i.e size wise.

Comment: It looks like the added a xdpi resource qualifier.  Is your drawable currently in the hdpi folder?  It may be scaling it up because of the screen density on the Xoom.

Comment: @CaseyB I have a folder called "drawable" under res and no other drawable- folders. Is that an issue? Should i create a new drawable-ldpi folder?

Comment: You should create a drawable-xdpi and put your images in there.  What happens is Android assumes that the images in the drawable folder are scaled for the G1 and it will scale them if it needs to.  If you put them in the drawable-xdpi it shouldn't scale them at all.

Comment: @CaseyB That'a a great point. When i moved the files (both pngs and xmls) from drawable to drawable-xdpi, the LayoutEditor shows the correct scaling. So, i compiled the project and installed the apk on the device. But, on device, it's still is of the same large size as before. I wonder why LayoutEditor and the device are behaving differently in this case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The xml files can stay in drawable since they don't have a resolution.  As for the device showing different results, try uninstalling the app from the Xoom and doing a clean on your project and reinstalling it.

Comment: I already tried uninstalling the app and cleaning of my project. I checked the timestamp of my apk file. Let me try to power cycle and see if that helps.

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  The only other thing I can think of is to make sure you have correctly specifies the <supports-screens> tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: @CaseyB. Turns out that the Xoom is an mdpi device. Someone else had the same issue - http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/146086. I am not sure if this is a limitation i have to live with.

Comment: Well, if you're only targeting the xoom you can change the name of the drawable-xdpi folder to drawable-mdpi and it should work.

Comment: @CaseyB. It does not seem to be working. There is absolutely no difference i can see on the device irrespective of which folder i place the pngs in. I even set the following in my manifest file -<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>

<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
anyDensity="true" />

Comment: Thank you for showing this to me...now my custom toggle works perfect!

Answer (score 6):

I figured out how to do this (centering a smaller background image inside a large ToggleButton) using [ScaleDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ScaleDrawable.html):

Set your ToggleButton to use a selector Drawable, as normal:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:variablePadding="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_selected_centered"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_default_white_centered"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_default_black_centered" />
</selector>
```

Then, make a ScaledDrawable for each of the items' drawables above, which points to your ACTUAL image file. e.g. ic_star_selected_centered.xml:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_selected"
    android:scaleGravity="center"
    android:scaleHeight="100%"
    android:scaleWidth="100%" 
     />
```

Finally, there is a [bug in Android that makes any ScaledDrawables invisible at first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507539/android-scaledrawable-doesnt-seems-to-work), until you set their level. So when inflating your view, call setLevel() from 1-10000 (1 is smallest scale, 10000 is full-sized):

```
    StateListDrawable star = (StateListDrawable) myToggleButton.getBackground();
    star.setLevel(5000); // centers the image at half size. shame on Android for using magic numbers!
```

Comment: I need to use your solution, but I can't understand where you use ScaleDrawable. Could you give us the entire solution to this?

Comment: ok, I got it, and works perfectly for me. Up vote for you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <inset android:insetLeft="15dp" android:insetRight="15dp" android:insetTop="15dp" android:insetBottom="15dp">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_star_selected_centered" />
        </inset>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <inset android:insetLeft="15dp" android:insetRight="15dp" android:insetTop="15dp" android:insetBottom="15dp">
            <bitmap android:src=" android:src="@drawable/ic_star_default_white_centered" />
        </inset>
    </item>

    <item >
        <inset android:insetLeft="15dp" android:insetRight="15dp" android:insetTop="15dp" android:insetBottom="15dp">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_star_default_black_centered" />
        </inset>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @caseyB had to say (look at the comments), i had to change the theme of the activity to achieve the intended effect. I think this is an issue on HoneyComb Xoom and may not be seen on phones.
Thanks for everyone for looking at my question and helping.

Answer (score -1):

"Quick and dirty" way of achieving this is to use relative layout and place your ImageView on top of the ToggleButton. Set `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` and set your onClick listener on the toggle

Said that - the other solution by CaseyB (customizing background files) is the right approach

Comment: That doesn't indicate whether the toggle is pressed or not, because by default toggle has on/off marker in the middle.  So this solution ends up looking just like a regular ImageButton.