# changing togglebutton's image after a dialog box prompt

Tags: android, image, listview, togglebutton, dialog

I have a MainAct that has a list view which lists all the objects, upon clicking on an item on the list, a dialog box prompt that allows the user to choose what he wants to do and there is a "set status" option, the status is displayed in the form of a togglebutton I tried using styles like [Setting image source for ToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100034/setting-image-source-for-togglebutton) but its not changing, not even with XML side or by .setBackgroundDrawable during run time. any pointers on what I should check?

Comment: So i just discovered the XML does not work but, the .setBackgroundDrawable is working but only if I move from an activity and back to this MainActivity, so considering my situation is that, the button should change after the message prompt, which lifecycle can i aim at? it seems that the activity goes to onResume() but the listadapter which holds the togglebutton does not get redrawn or am i missing a step? I tried listview.setAdapter() at the onResume function but, doesn't work hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, after dismissing the dialog box, call another time listview.setAdapter() it should solve the problem!