# Button with an image and text

Tags: android, button, scale, drawable, android-drawable

I have a button on which i put an image

I've been told i need to reduce the size of the image by 30%, so i created a scale drawable and put that in the selector of the button

unfortunately, the image does not display on the button as expected.

here is my code for the button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMain"
    style="@style/buttonMenuAppearance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_ic_main"
    android:text="@string/btnMain" />
```

my selector

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scaled_ic_main_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_main_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_main_normal" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_main_normal"></item>

    </selector>
```

my scaled drawable

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/ic_main_disabled"
android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:scaleHeight="30%"
android:scaleWidth="30%" />
```

the way it looked before the scale : 
      [image]

the way it looks after the scale : [image]

why isnt my image showing up ?

Answer (score 0):

Your "scaled image" is called "scale" not "scaled_ic_main_disabled" so your selector is not displaying anything (I guess you don't have any objects called "scaled_ic_main_disabled")

Change "scaled_ic_main_disabled" to "scale" in your selector.

Comment: the scale you are referring to is this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ScaleDrawable.html

Comment: I'm actually referring to the name of the XML element you created, like the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195206/scale-a-drawable-resource-in-xml-android

Comment: it wont let me add that, i don't have any file named scale

Comment: The code you posted above has xml called "scale" - what is that file called? I assumed you named it that, but maybe it's named properly. As another note - you are making it 30% of the original size, not reducing it 30%. And also only setting it for the disabled state - so I assume the button is disabled and it's not just having a build problem from a missing drawable.

Comment: it is ok if it is 30% of the original size, i will adjust that when the other problem is fixed. Yes the button is indeed disabled, it is disabled on start of the app, and that's the drawable i wanted to make. it is not missing any drawables

Comment: so your "scale" xml is in a file called "scaled_ic_main_disabled" and that file is in a drawable folder that is either generic or appropriate for your screen density? And "ic_main_disabled" is also in a drawable folder?

Comment: there are 3 drawables in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-xhdpi called "ic_main_disabled.png" those are the pictures, there is scale drawable in the drawable folder (without appendices) called "scaled_ic_main_disabled.xml" , the selector is also in the drawable folder, the same one "scaled_ic_main_disabled.xml" is in