# An Expand/Collapse button in Android (to show/hide an optional view)

Tags: android

I need a UI element that will allow the user to expand/collapse (show/hide) a view that contains optional/advanced information.

I envision this as a text label (e.g. 'advanced options', 'more/less') plus an icon that toggles between open and close.  I've got some icons that could serve the purpose, and the functionality of the element closely matches that of a ToggleButton, so I attempted to solve this problem with a styled ToggleButton.

This solution turned out to be super ugly (from the maintenance perspective).  I'll add it as an answer below.

I'm hoping someone could suggest a better solution, or point out how my solution could be simplified.

BTW, animating the expanding/collapsing of the view is addressed well in [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation).

Comment: I have created a library for this: https://github.com/salmaanahmed/SAExpandableButton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thankfully, I've found a much simpler way.

Instead of using a ToggleButton (which involved 11 resource files to style it) I'm just using a TextView with a CompoundDrawable, and then managing the state myself.

This way involves a little more code, but saves a huge mess of resource files.  It also makes it easier to handle multiple themes, e.g. here I set the resource ID's for the needed icons depending on the theme:

```
final MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();
if  (ma.isDarkTheme()) {
    icon_expand = getResources().getIdentifier( "ic_action_expand","drawable", ma.getPackageName() );       
    icon_collapse = getResources().getIdentifier( "ic_action_collapse","drawable", ma.getPackageName() );       
} else {
    icon_expand = getResources().getIdentifier( "ic_action_expand_light","drawable", ma.getPackageName() );     
    icon_collapse = getResources().getIdentifier( "ic_action_collapse_light","drawable", ma.getPackageName() );     
}
```

I do this in my fragment's onCreate.  It is unfortunate that I have to resolve the icon ID's at runtime, but that seems to be how it is done.

I have no idea why my icons are displayed at normal size in this case and at double size when I specified them as a layer of the background of the ToggleButton (which necessitating ScaledDrawable resources for all of my icons).

Here is my onClickListener (for the TextView):

```
protected OnClickListener expandCtrlListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        assertTrue( v == expandCtrl );
        isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        advancedView.setVisibility( isExpanded ?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
        expandCtrl.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( isExpanded ? icon_collapse : icon_expand, 0, 0, 0 );
    }
};
```

Note that none of this shows the animation of the expand/collapse.  That is addressed in the article I mention at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the question, the functionality of the button closely matches ToggleButton so I started with a layout that shows a styled ToggleButton next to some text:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp" >
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/expcollButton"
        style="@style/expCollToggleBtn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expandText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/expcollButton"
        android:text="Show Options" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The style (in styles.xml file) looks like this.  This nulls out the button text and points to the background drawable.

```
<style name="expCollToggleBtn">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/expcoll_btn_toggle_bg_light</item>
    <item name="android:textOn"></item>
    <item name="android:textOff"></item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
</style>
```

The background drawable is a layer-list xml file that points to another drawable (perhaps there is some way to get rid of this file and just point directly to the selector below?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@drawable/expcoll_btn_toggle" />
</layer-list>
```

The selector lists the images for open/closed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_expand" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_collapse" />
</selector>
```

Now, the first complication is that this results in a very oversized button/image.  I've provided suitable images for all pixel densities, so I'm not sure why this is happening, but the solution is to scale the images.

Unfortunately, this seems to require a ScaledDrawable for every image.  I actually have four images because I foolishly decided to support light and dark themes in my app.  So I need four of these.

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_expand"
    android:scaleGravity="center"
    android:scaleHeight="50%"
    android:scaleWidth="50%" 
/>
```

Also, note that there is a bug in ScaledDrawables, [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507539/android-scaledrawable-doesnt-seems-to-work), so that needs to be accounted for.

And finally, since I'm trying to support two themes I need multiple copies of the selector and the layer-list files too, and need to add attributes to the attrs.xml file.  At this point, I've got 11 XML files involved (plus the 10 image files for all the densities) all for a pretty ordinary button.

This can't be right!

Answer (score 0):

**A simple Expand Collapse Code**

```
   //show/hide boxes panel
    var expansion: Boolean = false

    expand_up.setOnClickListener {
        if (!expansion) {
            expand_up.setImageResource(R.drawable.collapse)
            boxes_panel.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            expansion = true
        }
        else{
            expand_up.setImageResource(R.drawable.expand)
            boxes_panel.visibility = View.GONE
            expansion = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a library for this.
It is called SAExpandableButton, you can find it [here](https://github.com/salmaanahmed/SAExpandableButton)

[image]